# Is $O(n^{1/2})$ exponential? Is $O(n)$ better than $O(n^{1/2})$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was just going through some of the primality test algorithms. It seems that the regular one – loop up to square root of $n$ – has running time $O(n^{1/2})$.

Is $O(n^{1/2})$ exponential? And is exponential time better than polynomial always?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 6):

A function that is $O(n^{1/2}) = O(\sqrt{n})$ is a polynomial, not an exponential, function of $n$. However, when analyzing the run-time of algorithms, we need to be clear about what $n$ actually is.

Here, $n$ is the (value of the) number whose primality is being tested. However, we measure the run-time of the algorithm in terms of the length of its input in bits. The number $n$ can be represented in $\log n$ bits, which means that the running time of $O(n^{1/2})$ is actually exponential in the length of the input.

Comment: so is O(n^1/2) better than O(n)?

Comment: I don't know. Is $\pi$ better than $7$? What does "better" mean?

Comment: Runtime complexity of O(n^1/2) is better than O(n)?

Comment: It's impossible to say, because $O(\cdot)$ just gives an upper bound. If envelope A contains less than ten dollars and envelope B contains less than a hundred dollars, which contains most money? You don't know, because it could be that A contains \$9 but B contains only \$1. Similarly, $\sqrt{n}<n$ but some functions that are in $O(\sqrt{n})$ are bigger than some functions that are in $O(n)$.